# VBA - Dynamic Charts

Tags: excel, vba

I have a really useful piece of VBA code that creates dynamic charts depending on how many rows of data are populated by the users dataset.

```
With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
    LastRow = .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).END(xlUp).row
    Set Rng1 = .Range("R2:R" & LastRow & ", S2:S" & LastRow)
    ShName = .Name
End With
With Sheets("Property Details").ChartObjects("Year").Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
End With
```

However I have noticed that when I have values of only one row (see below):

[image]

my piece of code doesn't read the category name. It populates the chart with 1 rather than the name (see below)

[image]

I suspect it is how it is setting the range:

```
Set Rng1 = .Range("R2:R" & LastRow & ", S2:S" & LastRow)
```

and its not liking the "R2:R2" in the chart but I'm not sure how you build a work around in

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The issue - Why is this?

If you set the data source with `.SetSourceData Source:=` you actually let Excel guess how the data in that range is arranged. If it is more than one row in that range, then Excel can analyze and guess that pretty good.

But with only one row of data Excel cannot determine properly which of the text data the chart title is and which the row/category name.

#### Solving it …

That means you must be more precise in your definition.

For example if you include row 1 the guessing gets a bit better:

```
Set Rng1 = .Range("R1:R" & LastRow & ", S1:S" & LastRow)
```

but then chart title and category name flip to Excel's default and the result is:

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: The chart title and the category name flipped. Excel's guess was not the expected result.</sup>*

If you are more precise and tell Excel exactly which data is where in that range, then you will get a precise result:

```
With Sheets("Property Details").ChartObjects("Year").Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='" & ShName & "'!$S$1"                     '≙ "=DynamicCharts!$S$1"
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$S$2:$S$" & LastRow     '≙ "=DynamicCharts!$S$2:$S$" & LastRow
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & ShName & "'!$R$2:$R$" & LastRow    '≙ "=DynamicCharts!$R$2:$R$" & LastRow
End With
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: With a precise definition where which data is, Excel doesn't need to  guess and you get the desired result.</sup>*

#### Conlusion

Excel is very patient if you are not giving precise instuctions what exactly to do. So it will guess and present a result (which might not be what you expected). But the more precise the instructions you give, the less Excel guesses and the more precise and reliable the result is.

Best practice: Always be as precise as possible to avoid surprises :)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a brilliant solution with a really good explanation. Makes complete sense. I do have an additional comment. Do you know how you might incorporate this into a chart with two ranges?

Comment: With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
        LastRow = .Range("BZ" & .Rows.Count).END(xlUp).row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow & ", CC2:CC" & LastRow)
        Set Rng2 = .Range("CD2:CD" & LastRow)
End With

  With Sheets("Property Details").ChartObjects("Roof").Chart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Value"
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .Values = Rng2
            .AxisGroup = 2
            .Name = "Price"
    End With
End With

Comment: PEH, apologies if I should message you this in another way but I am unsure.

Comment: @Carlos80 Please open up a new question for that. As you see the code get's unreadable in comments.

Comment: Hi PEH, apologies I thought this might be the case but wasn't sure as it was a follow up. Thanks for your advice, I have posted the second question here if you do get a chance to see it. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838585/vba-dynamic-charts-with-two-ranges